# Rspec controller error expecting <"index"> but rendering with <"">

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, devise, cancan

New to testing, I'm struggling to get some controller tests to pass.

The following controller test throws the error:

```
   expecting <"index"> but rendering with <"">
```

I have the following in one of my controller specs:

```
  require 'spec_helper'

  describe NasController do

  render_views
  login_user

  describe "GET #nas" do
      it "populates an array of devices" do
        @location = FactoryGirl.create(:location)
        @location.users << @current_user
        @nas = FactoryGirl.create(:nas, location_id: @location.id )      
        get :index
        assigns(:nas).should eq([@nas])
      end

      it "renders the :index view" do
        response.should render_template(:index)
      end
    end
```

In my controller macros, I have this:

```
  def login_user
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      @current_user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      @current_user.roles << Role.first
      sign_in @current_user
      User.current_user = @current_user
      @user = @current_user
      @ability = Ability.new(@current_user)
    end
  end
```

I'm using devise and cancan and have followed their guides re. testing. I believe my users are signed in before and have the ability to view the index action.

What can I do to get the tests to pass?

-- UPDATE 1 --

Controller code:

```
class NasController < ApplicationController
   before_filter :authenticate_user!
   load_and_authorize_resource

   respond_to :js

   def index

     if params[:location_id]
       ...
     else
     @nas = Nas.accessible_by(current_ability).page(params[:page]).order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction)

     respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
     end    
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think if you change

```
it "renders the :index view" do
  response.should render_template(:index)
end
```

to

```
it "renders the :index view" do
  get :index
  response.should render_template(:index)
end
```

it should work.

update: try this

```
it "renders the :index view" do
  @location = FactoryGirl.create(:location)
  @location.users << @current_user
  @nas = FactoryGirl.create(:nas, location_id: @location.id ) 
  get :index
  response.should render_template(:index)
end
```

Comment: Hey. That still fails. Tried it earlier - also tried to repeat the location creation. Don't get it. The same test passes in another controller.

Comment: Is their something in your controller that prevents you from bringing up the index if the naz table is empty?

Comment: Nope, and I've tried removing both the devise and cancan filters. And replacing the find with @nas = Nas.all Just in case. Frustrating!

Comment: does your index method in your controller contain a redirect_to anywhere?

Comment: It would help if you could post your controller code for the index action and anything else relevant.

Comment: `login_user` should go in a `before(:each)` block

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this error on my end, but no idea if we're having the same problem.

In my setup, I had a controller macro that would loop through each response format (html, js, json, etc.) and test the specs under that format.  Like an idiot, I didn't actually have a json response template in existance for some of my specs yet, and I didn't realize that this will throw an error if it can't actually find the template.  So that was my issue.

Try specifying a format in your in your specs like below, and just write up some mock template named index.html in the correct folder and see if you get the same error.

```
get :index, :format => "html"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Have tried but this doesn't work for me. Am going to see if I can get it to work in another controller and see differences.